# How to set a max height of a any kind of view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-scrollview

### Background

I'm trying to put a view within a container view, so that the container will allow the view to have any height (and/or width,depending on your specification) , yet not pass a specific one.

### The problem

There is no way to define "maxHeight" for any kind of view. You can only use exact size , use some tricks to take the spare size (layout_weight) or make the scrollView take as much space as it needs.

The only similar thing is for EditText , which you can use "maxLines" together with "setMovementMethod", as shown [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3256305/878126) .

### What I've tried

I've tried to make the next viewGroup that contains the scrollView, but it didn't work as expected:

```
public class SizeLimitLayout extends FrameLayout {
    private int mMaxHeightInPixels = -1;
    private int mMaxWidthInPixels = -1;

    public SizeLimitLayout(final Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SizeLimitLayout(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SizeLimitLayout(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public void setMaxHeight(final int maxHeightInPixels) {
        this.mMaxHeightInPixels = maxHeightInPixels;
    }

    public void setMaxWidth(final int maxWidthInPixels) {
        this.mMaxWidthInPixels = maxWidthInPixels;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(final int widthMeasureSpec, final int heightMeasureSpec) {
        // time to decide what is the size of this view
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        int width = getMeasuredWidth(), height = getMeasuredHeight();
        if (mMaxWidthInPixels >= 0)
            width = Math.min(mMaxWidthInPixels, width);
        if (mMaxHeightInPixels >= 0)
            height = Math.min(mMaxHeightInPixels, height);
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    }
}
```

Here's a sample of how I tried to use what I made:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final SizeLimitLayout sizeLimitLayout = (SizeLimitLayout) findViewById(R.id.sizeLimitLayout);
        sizeLimitLayout.setMaxHeight((int) convertDpToPixels(this, 160));
        final View btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
        final ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.container);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View v) {
                final ImageView iv = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                container.addView(iv);
            }
        });
    }

    public static float convertDpToPixels(final Context context, final float dp) {
        final float pixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dp, context.getResources()
                .getDisplayMetrics());
        return pixels;
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.viewsizelimittest.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="click"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <com.example.viewsizelimittest.SizeLimitLayout
        android:id="@+id/sizeLimitLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#33ff0000"
            android:fillViewport="true" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </com.example.viewsizelimittest.SizeLimitLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### The question

The code almost works, but the container doesn't allow to scroll .

What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't build it row limiter but in this question there are some solutions that might help to solve your problem
[EditText maxLines not working - user can still input more lines than set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7092961/edittext-maxlines-not-working-user-can-still-input-more-lines-than-set)

Comment: I don't want to have a maxLines, as it limits the lines the user can enter. I want the user to be able to enter as much as he needs, and that if the EditText gets too large in height, it will stick to the max height and then be able to scroll. Also, just because I wrote that I do it for an EditText doesn't mean I won't need it for other views. I want it to be used for any kind of view.

Comment: Anyway, I've updated my question as the EditText was just an example. BTW, for EditText, you can use this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3256305/878126